# Compatibility of the absolute value with the integration

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, integration

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and $L^{1}(H)$ be the space of trace class operators on $H$.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to L^{1}(H)$ be a  measurable function that is $t\to \operatorname{tr}(f(t))$ is Borel measurable.

> Q.  Suppose that $\int \operatorname{tr}(f(t))d\mu$ is finite. Can we conclude that $\int \operatorname{tr}(|f(t)|)d\mu$ is finite too?

Comment: What does $\lvert f(t)\rvert$ mean?  (That is, what is the absolute value of a trace-class operator?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if $H$ is two dimensional, $\mu$ = Lebesgue measure and
$$
f(t) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\0 &-1\end{bmatrix}
$$
so that $\mathrm{tr}(f(t))=0$

Then I guess
$$
|f(t)| = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\0 &1\end{bmatrix}
$$
so that $\mathrm{tr}\big(|f(t)|\big) = 2$ is not integrable.